# Error in ajax check availability

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

EDIT: SOLVED after 5 mins :D
Change `url: "admin/check-ma-sach.php"` to `url: "../check-ma-sach.php"`, because it read from index.php, not main.js

I want to check if input[#masach] existed, go ahead, if not, exit

Here is the code:

```
<input type="text" name="masach" id="masach" onBlur="checkmasach()">
<span id="check-ma-sach-status"></span>
<script src="../../lib/main.js"></script>`
```

main.js file:

```
function checkmasach() {
   jQuery.ajax({
   url: "admin/check-ma-sach.php",
   data:'masach='+$("#masach").val(),
   type: "POST",
   success:function(data){
    $("#check-ma-sach-status").html(data);      
   },
   error:function (){}
   });
}
```

check-ma-sach.php file

```
<?php
require_once("../lib/connection.php");    
if(!empty($_POST["masach"])) {
  $masach = htmlspecialchars($_POST["masach"]);
  $result = mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT count(*) FROM tonghopsach WHERE masach='" . $masach . "'");
  if($result === FALSE) {die(mysqli_error());}
  $row = mysqli_fetch_row($result);
  $user_count = $row[0];
  if($user_count>0) {
      // do nothing          
  }else{
      echo 'Exactly!';         
  }
}?>
```

Directory tree:

```
- admin
- - check-ma-sach.php
- - sach
- - - index.php
- lib
- - connection.php
- - main.js
```

I have checked connection to php and js files correctly but when run HTML, it appears a 404 message.
What's the reason?

Answer (score 0):

Error 404 is page not found , change admin/check-ma-sach.php  to /admin/check-ma-sach.php

Comment: `url: "admin/check-ma-sach.php",`
you mean this url ?!?